# Make 1st Slide of PowerPoint file to be the Post thumbnail preview image

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm building a website for a client.. The website will only accept PowerPoint files to be uploaded in our server by our future members and soon we will start accepting online links.. I would like to ask for your help. We need to show the first slide of the PowerPoint file as the thumbnail preview image post without asking our members to upload .jpg files for the featured image. We want to automate the process.. by not making .jpg files from each PowerPoint files submitted to the website..

Hope to hear from you soon and I really appreciate your time for giving a me solution for this matter..

Thank You.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Your question is a very broad one, and as such is [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please [edit it](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/381779/edit) to tell us a) what you've tried and b) what *specific* WordPress programming-related problem you're running into. If you're looking for someone to write a plugin for you, I'm afraid you've come to the wrong place.

Comment: do you have PHP code to render the first slide? If you know how to generate the JPEG you could ask how to attach it, but opening and rendering powerpoint slides isn't a WordPress question

Comment: "We want to automate the process by not making .jpg files from each PowerPoint files submitted to the website" - I don't understand. Where do you want to get the thumbnails from then? Or did you mean not having to do this by hand?

Comment: Note that PPTX files might contain a docProps/thumbnail.jpeg file in the .zip you can just use, but it's probably fairly low res. Or you'll probably have to find a service that will make a thumbnail from a PPTX for you, or set up your own e.g. using OpenOffice on a headless X desktop.

Comment: Maybe this library can help: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation